# ASP.NET MVC 5 Random 404, changing case works

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-404

I have an MVC 5 site which when on the production server some pages will start returning 404s but changing the address case will load the page. For example

Calling /Checkout will be working and then randomly will return a 404 but then changing my address to /checkout the page will return ok. Then change to /Checkout again and I get the 404 etc.

Restart the site in ISS and the problem goes away temporally.

Does anyone know what might cause this?

I have added failed request tracing to try and dive a little deeper but any other suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint server side at the designated controller, does it break?

Comment: problem is that it is running on a live production server so I can't add break points etc. Failed request tracing is not showing anything obvious either.